# Formatting the Display of Multi-Lined addtocontents Entries

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, line-breaking, indentation

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}\large
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 10pt}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect {III. The words of this sentence are quite a few; I would like the second line of this sentence to begin under "The".}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}


\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 10pt}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect {IV. In this long TOC entry, I would like the second line to begin under the "In".}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the second line of these long TOC entries to be indented; and if possible, to begin under the first word of the first line after the Roman numeral. How may I do this. (I am approaching the task this way because I do not want any dots or page numbers to appear.)

Also, does anyone know why the second entry is indented, whereas the first entry is not?

Comment: Can't you use normal `\section` commands with simple Roman section numbering??